# Multiplication equivalent of diff in R

Tags: arrays, r, diff

I have a very simple question.

I need to multiply two values of the same column with a consistent lag for the whole column. For example, to simply use difference I can do

```
(c(rep(NA,11),diff(data$x,lag=11))-data$y)*1000*data$i/data$j
```

I was wondering if there is an equivalent (or simpler method) for multiplying the values instead of subtracting.

Cheers!

JT

Comment: This is probably not what you want, but for the multiplicative equivalent to `diff`, you could use `log` and `exp` as follows: `exp(diff(log(x)))`.

Comment: `tail(x,-lag) * head(x,-lag)`

Comment: @Roland, this was the most easiest answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Roland You should probably leave those as answers as I found them helpful.